# UML Use case help - how do you show a use case that actor cannot access?

Tags: uml, use-case-diagram

Example of controlling a security camera online. user can pan camera, take a snapshot etc through an web browser. How do I draw a use case when user encounter problems eg. the network is down, unable to pan camera.

Answer (score 0):

The use case is still the same `Control area with camera`. What you now see is an error path in a scenario. This is business as usual. The error path will likely be to start camera maintenance (as another use case called `Maintain defect camera`). You might need to extend the UC with another one called `Control area manually`.